# Implement OAuth2 with resource owner password credentials on Android

Tags: android, spring, authentication, oauth

I need to make calls to services which are secured by OAuth2 resource owner password credentials. I tried all the libraries on oauth.net/code, but with no success. All of them seem not to provide this kind of authentication, but seem to be great with 3 legged authentication.

My user should login with username and password, but I do not want to store username and password. I want to get an access token and refresh this token from time to time.

My network communication is currently based on spring 4 android and the resttemplate you can find there.

Any suggestions, which library I could use? I think this is a common problem.

Comment: [This sample client](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/security/library/se-oathjavapt1/index.html) from IBM developer seems to support resource owner credential grant ([Download the sample source](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/apps/download/index.jsp?contentid=959474&filename=OAuth20.zip&method=http&locale=)). Spring security oauth client, google oauth client, leelo, and others simply don't support this grant type! It's no surprise as this grant type is the least attracting among the four.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find anything either, so I've put together a library myself, and I am releasing it to the public.

**Usage:**

```
import org.sdf.danielsz.OAuth2Client;
import org.sdf.danielsz.Token;

OAuth2Client client = new OAuth2Client(username, password, app-id, app-secret, site);
Token token = client.getAccessToken();

token.getResource(client, token, "/path/to/resource?name=value");
```

With this grant type, the client application doesn't need to store the username/password of the user. Those credentials are asked once and exchanged for an access token. This token can then be used to access protected resources.

To check if a token has expired:

```
token.isExpired();
```

To manually refresh a token:

```
Token newToken = token.refresh(client);
```

A more involved example can be found in the [README](https://github.com/danielsz/android-oauth2-client) on github.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I'll check it out.

Comment: I used your code as base. It's very useful, but you implemented some fallbacks with basic authentication i don't need. And i added the calls in interception code.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this url : https://temboo.com/library/Library/Fitbit/OAuth/ and https://temboo.com/library/Library/Fitbit/OAuth/InitializeOAuth/

In order to run java code to generate OAuth url, you will need temboo.jar file which you can download by clicking on java icon on right hand side link.

cheers.

Comment: don't post links directly.

Comment: Links above don't address the resource owner password grant type. Please read this: http://alexbilbie.com/2013/02/a-guide-to-oauth-2-grants/